# how to use ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am not able to access array values one by one here is `plunker`

https://plnkr.co/edit/58HdYqZUi30kRaNgT3V3?p=preview

I am just accessing this, but it is not printing anything.

```
     <div ng-repeat=" day in excDays">
     <p>{{day}}</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: i have corrected it based on below comments now it works fine

Comment: Mark as answered then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the `<div>` without printing anything in it:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in excDays">
    <span ng-bind="day"></span>
</div>
```

The values from the `ng-repeat` are only available inside the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this   , You have to put `{{day}}` inside `ng-repeat div`

```
   <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="day in excDays">
        <p>{{day.dayName}}</p>
        </div>
  </body>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.excDays = [
       {
     dayNum: 1,
     dayName: 'Monday'
    }, {
     dayNum: 2,
     dayName: 'Tuesday'
    }, {
     dayNum: 3,
     dayName: 'Wednesday'
    }, {
     dayNum: 4,
     dayName: 'Thursday'
    }, {
     dayNum: 5,
     dayName: 'Friday'
    }, {
     dayNum: 6,
     dayName: 'Saturday'
    },{
     dayNum: 0,
     dayName: 'Sunday'
      }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="day in excDays">
    <p>{{day.dayName}}</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `p` inside the `div` with the `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="day in excDays">
  <p>{{day}}</p>
</div>
```

Updated plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/1JKLBRe4wfS6SPXNKz7t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `day` is only usable inside the `div`, and you are closing it and then you call `day` outside of that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

---

Yo should place `<p>` inside `<div>` tag. `{{day}}` is out of scope.